# ROS and GAZEBO installation in Debian

Tags: ros, gazebo, installation, debian

I'm new to using ROS and Gazebo. Just now, I'm writing a couple of scripts to automate the installation of ROS and Gazebo in Xubuntu 22.04 LTS. However, I would like to install ROS and Gazebo in Debian Trixie or Bookworm. Exploring the ROS repositories, I [found here](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros2/dists/) a ROS package for Debian Bookworm, nevertheless in the Gazebo repositories I only found a [package for Debian Buster](http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/debian-stable/dists/) (the most recent).

The question is, does someone know how to install ROS and Gazebo in Debian Bookworm or Trixie?

Thanks a lot.